# Django: How to center forms on html template in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to simply center a form that has been rendered on a Django html template. It is a bootstrap component (form), and I have tried putting the 'center' html tags in various places but with no success. I have tried putting the center tags outside the form, outside the Django templating language blocks, and in the base template, outside the div.

Could someone please advise on a) how to solve the problem b) best practices for applying formatting, as in this case.

Someone tried to edit this suggesting it has nothing to do with Django, but it does. Centering is simple otherwise, but I want to understand it the context of using base templates and django's templating language blocks.

**page.html (that extends base2.html)**

```
{% extends "socialmedia/base2.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}Welcome to the test page{% endblock %}
{% block heading %}Welcome,,,,{% endblock %}
<center>
{% block content1 %}
<class="form-group row">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Radios</legend>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="gridRadios1" value="option1" checked>
          <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios1">
            First radio
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="gridRadios2" value="option2">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios2">
            Second radio
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check disabled">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="gridRadios3" value="option3" disabled>
          <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios3">
            Third disabled radio
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">Checkbox</div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
          Example checkbox
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>


{% endblock %}
</center>
```

**base2.html (from which the above file inherits)**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'worldguestbook\main2.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>{% block title %}My amazing site{% endblock %}</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>{% block heading %}My amazing site{% endblock %}</h1>

    <div id="content1">
        {% block content1 %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I still doubt django has anything to do with it; Django's templates are finally converted to plain HTML files before they reach the browser. A `row` is 100% width of its parent. Limit the parent container's size and set `margin: auto;`. That should centre the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below tag for form It might work

```
<form ALIGN='center'>
</form>
```

Comment: The `align` attribute is deprecated for any elements other than `col`, `colgroup`, `tbody`, `td`, `tfoot`, `th`, `thead`, and `tr`. [More info](https://www.w3resource.com/html/attributes/html-align-attribute.php).

Comment: No - it doesn't. Thanks though. I think my real question is, when you are applying additionals to code added to a tempalte that is extending a base template, where do you put things (for instance, if I had javascript code that needs to go into the head to apply formatting to something in the body), where do I put it, as there are no head tags in the inherting template, and only in the base?